# How to extract Woo Commerce Gift Card redeemed value from data using Smart Coupon

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I extract gift card redeemed *value* from Woo Commerce order using PHP and WC classes?

I have an e-commerce site using wordpress and woo-commerce, now using the smart-coupon woocommerce plugin extension.  I am trying to parse out the order discount **separately** from any gift cards redeemed for an order to capture and process correctly for our ERP system.   I am attempting to use the WC Classes available but have not been able to drill down to this specific data.  When I use the get_data function of the order object, created using WC_Order(),  I can see the value buried in WC_Coupon_Item_Coupon object showing [private] or [protected] – see clip below with value desired (***[discount] => 3*** in below text).  How can I extract this data value?
Thanks very much ~ Lisa

Snippet of what get_data() is returning:

```
[90093] => WC_Order_Item_Coupon Object
            (
                [extra_data:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [code] => 
                        [discount] => 0
                        [discount_tax] => 0
                    )

                [data:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [order_id] => 49902
                        [name] => 
                        [code] => giftcardpattest
                        [discount] => 3
                        [discount_tax] => 0
                    )
```

Comment: When you are testing the output, you should pretty print it. `echo "<pre>".print_r($array, true)."</pre>"` This way it's a bit more readable.

Comment: print_r is exactly what I used but I will try this to help formatting ~ thank you!

Comment: [90093] => WC_Order_Item_Coupon Object
                ([extra_data:protected] => Array
                        ([code] => 
                            [discount] => 0
                            [discount_tax] => 0)

                    [data:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [order_id] => 49902
                            [name] => 
                            [code] => giftcardpattest
                            [discount] => 3
                            [discount_tax] => 0

Comment: If you could update your question, and put the contents of the `print_r` in a code box (I believe is correct) it should display properly on the page.

Answer (score 0):

We are trying to extract the data via the API.  The question really is how can we access the discount of coupons via the api?  Get_Used_coupons() only returns the names.  We can't figure out how to get what is given in discount on an order via wc_coupon, or wc_order_item_coupon.  The get_discount() method doesn't seem to get the discount applied to the order.  The data is clearly there, as Lisa pointed out, but the methods are not returning what is applied to the order.  How do we access it appropriately via the api?  We can likely query the data via MySQL, or by drilling through the object, but we'd prefer a method the retains functionality when the database and objects get updated and changed.  To make the puzzle slightly more challenging, both giftcards and coupons can be used for an order and both show as a coupon.  For accounting purposes we need to apply each of these differently and so need to know how much was used for each.  The data is clearly there we simple are have difficulty accessing it via the api.